# Loading div from separate page into another page with or w/o refresh

Tags: php, html, load, pull

I want to "pull" or "load" an entire div from a separate page and display it on another page within a div.

I'm updating the home page's "latest news" div whenever the actual page for latest news is updated.

I would like to use php for this and I do not want the entire 2nd page to display, only the information in the div.

Thanks for any advice/suggestions,

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

I recommend jQuery framework with `load()`.

See documentation: [load() - Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [DOM classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to remotely fetch the page and parse the HTML element text...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php');
$div = $dom->getElementById('book.dom');
echo $div->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather you're attempting to replicate an AJAX-style loading of content from an external source into your page.  I've been thinking about this for a little bit, and I think it can be done.

You'd need to do the following:

1: Load the external page using curl, url fopen or similar.  I'd recommend curl.
2: Initialize a DomDocument object if the page fetch is successful.
3: Use the DOM traversal functions to locate the div and retrieve its contents. 
4: Insert the contents into your page with the method of your choice.

I've not attempted an actual implementation, as this is just an idea as to how to go about it.  Hopefully though it will give you enough information to make a start.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with jQuery and the method load():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        $("#news_div").load("/news.php");
    }, 10000);
});
```

This would load news.php every 10th second and inject it in the div with the ID `news_div`.

However, you're better off looking at node.js, sockets et.c. if you have a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @harakiri comment, you can also look into JQuery's live function which does basically the same, but in case you need future binding done automagically, live will do that opposed to load.